# View em projeto MVC em PHP

Tags: php, mvc, view

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto MVC em PHP e fiz toda a view em arquivos.html.
Quando preciso manipular um form, especifico na action o caminho para um script no controller. A minha dúvida é se é necessário fazer a view apenas em arquivos .html sem nada de php. Além disso, preciso implementar um sistema de login fazendo com que eu tenha que implementar alguma forma de controle de login em php nas páginas html.Como eu procederia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A **view** é a onde você vai colocar a saída da sua aplicação, mas muitas vezes se torna necessário fazer alguma codificação, portanto você pode criar views com extensão .php.

**Ilustrando**:
Supondo que você tenha que listar os usuários cadastrados de um sistema, você só consegue fazer isso, se você tiver views com extensão .php ou .phtml;

Isso é necessário pois, você precisa executar códigos php nessa view.

**Login**:
Em relação ao login, você pode fazer o gerenciamento das sessões através dos Controllers e a saída nas Views.

Comment: **Errado**. Vários frameworks suportam views em *html* por fazerem uso de *template engine*.

Comment: Concordo plenamente com o @Gustavo Carvalho, a ideia da view eh nao usar logica de negocio, nao importa o codigo que voce ira utilizar na view, o importante eh nao misturar a logica de negocio com a visualizacao.

Comment: @Papa Charlie, não estou dizendo que não pode ter views .html, estou informando que caso necessário vc pode ter views .php ( para listagens, etc );

Comment: Este projeto pode ajudar http://dwoo.org/, uso ele sempre, as views ficam em formato .tpl