# Código PHP apenas não inicia ao carregar a página!

Tags: php, mysqli

Fiz o código abaixo para mostrar os arquivos que foram inseridos pelo usuário, porém ele só mostra os arquivos após ter anexado um arquivo, porém eu queria que ele mostrasse ao carregar a página, para o usuário ver quais arquivos ele já fez o upload.
Esse é o código que usei para fazer o upload do arquivo:

## Plano de aula 1

```
    $arq = str_replace(" ", "_", $arq);
    $arq = str_replace("ç", "c", $arq);

    if (file_exists("uploads/".$arq)) {
      $a = 1;

      while (file_exists("uploads/[".$a."]".$arq)) {
        $a++;
      }

      $arq = "[".$a."]".$arq;
    }

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/'.$arq)) {
      $objDb = new db();
      $link = $objDb->conecta_mysql();
      $sql = "insert into arquivos (email_vol, nomearq) values ('".  $email."', '".$arq."')";
      if (mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
        echo 'Plano de aula 1 enviado com sucesso!';
      } else {
        echo (mysqli_error($link));
        echo 'Erro ao enviar o plano de aula!';
      }

    } else {
      echo "Nenhum arquivo selecionado!";
    }

  }
  ?>
</p></center>
```

Esse é o código para mostrar o arquivo na página:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="text-center">
       <h1 class="tittlenoticia" style="color: black;">Arquivos anexados</h1>
       <?php
       require_once('conecta.php');
       $pasta = "uploads/";
       $consulta = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM arquivos WHERE email_vol = '$email'");
        while ($resultado = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)) {
            echo "<a href=\"" . $pasta . $resultado["nomearq"] . "\">" . $resultado["nomearq"] . "</a><br />";
        } 
       ?>

  </div>
</div>
```

Alguém pode me dar uma ajuda? Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Não é muito legal executar uma query dentro da view. Você precisa separar as responsábilidades. Isso facilita até mesmo na hora de debugar a sua aplicação. Você pode trabalhar com MVC, ou estruturado com MV somente, sem o controller. Existem vários padrões... mas por favor, query na view é uma péssima prática.

Comment: @ThiagoCunha eu realmente desconheço esse MVC, comecei a aprender php agora.

Comment: Compreendo! Coloque pelo menos as suas querys em seu modelo de negócios, ou seja, no Model.
Achei essa questão que deve servir de grande ajuda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/67699/view-em-projeto-mvc-em-php

Comment: @ThiagoCunha Só pro meu entendimento, isso seria fazer em um arquivo toda a view da página, e em um arquivo separado fazer os códigos php, e chamar esses códigos na view?